# Вставить текст в body письма через url OWA

Tags: javascript, html, html5

```
Есть ссылка, по открытию которой открывается Outlook Web Api с формой создания нового письма. 

https://owa.rogaikopita.ru/owa/?ae=Item&a=New&t=IPM.Note&to=imst%40rogaikopita.ru&subject=130000027&body=Body%20Text

Как прямо в URL вставить текст в body ? (возможно ли?)
Тема письма заполняется без проблем
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Main:[Outlook Mail REST API reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/mail-rest-operations?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

2.Send message:[Send a new message on the fly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/mail-rest-operations#SendMessageOnTheFly)

Comment: Можно пример как формируется POST запрос в JS ? А за ссылки огромное спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Типовой пример POST-запроса в JQuery AJAX:

```js
/* Get from elements values */
 var values = $(this).serialize();

 $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "post",
        data: values ,
        success: function (response) {
           // you will get response from your php page (what you echo or print)                 

        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
        }


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="foo">
    <label for="bar">A bar</label>
    <input id="bar" name="bar" type="text" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

<!-- The result of the search will be rendered inside this div -->
<div id="result"></div>
```

POST-запрос в JavaScript:

```js
function submitform()
   {
       var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName("inputs");
       var formdata = new FormData();
       for(var i=0; i<inputs.length; i++)
       {
           formdata.append(inputs[i].name, inputs[i].value);
       }
       var xmlhttp;
       if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
       {
           xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest;
       }
       else
       {
           xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
       }
       xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
       {
          if(xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
          {

          }
       }
       xmlhttp.open("POST", "test.php");
       xmlhttp.send(formdata);
   }
```

```html
 <form name="foo" action="form.php" method="POST" id="foo">
        <label for="bar">A bar</label>
        <input id="bar" class="inputs" name="bar" type="text" value="" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send" onclick="submitform(); return false;" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!